# Difference between map controls in Xamarin map app?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

I'm new to Xamarin Forms, and I'm trying to understand how everything works.

I downloaded and ran the maps application in this [Xamarin working with Maps](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/WorkingWithMaps/) link. It runs perfectly in the android emulator. I'm now trying to understand how the code works.

This is the first screen I see when I debug the app. It's the regular Google Maps that I'm used to:

[image]

When I click the last tab, this is what I see:

[image]

It shows a warning saying *"These buttons leave the current app and open the built-in Maps app for the platform"*. When I click on *OPEN LOCATION USING BUILT-IN MAPS APP* I see another Google Map similar to the first Google map that I saw: 
[image]

From what I understand, the first map is shown in `Xamarin.Forms` while the second map is from the Android project.

Two questions:

- Regarding the specific functionality of this app (specifically Android and Xamarin.Forms), Is there any difference between the first map and the last map?
- The last map has a small tab at the bottom that displays information on the pin (ie. "394 Pacific Ave, San Francisco, CA 94111, USA"). Can this *popup* tab be created on Xamarin.Forms or is it something that can only be accomplished in the Android project?

Answer (score 0):

> Regarding the specific functionality of this app (specifically Android and Xamarin.Forms), Is there any difference between the first map and the last map?>

Yes, they are different, one is an embedded map in your app and the other is a completely different app. On Android, that last map page is asking Android to launch a Uri that starts with an  scheme value of `geo:`.

```
geo:0,0?q=394+Pacific+Ave+San+Francisco+CA
```

From there, the Android OS will look for all installed apps that support that `geo:` scheme. Typically most Android images will have Google Maps pre-installed and if that is the only `geo:` scheme supporter it directly launches that app otherwise you would be prompted which mapping app to use. You are now in an external app and your Xamarin.Forms app is no longer running (until you hit the back button, thus closing that app and returning to your Forms app).

```
~~~
if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS) {
    //https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/MapLinks/MapLinks.html
    Device.OpenUri(new Uri("http://maps.apple.com/?q=394+Pacific+Ave+San+Francisco+CA"));
} else if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.Android) {
    // opens the Maps app directly
    Device.OpenUri(new Uri("geo:0,0?q=394+Pacific+Ave+San+Francisco+CA"));
} else if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.UWP) {
    Device.OpenUri(new Uri("bingmaps:?where=394 Pacific Ave San Francisco CA"));
}
~~~
```

> The last map has a small tab at the bottom that displays information on the pin (ie. "394 Pacific Ave, San Francisco, CA 94111, USA"). Can this popup tab be created on Xamarin.Forms or is it something that can only be accomplished in the Android project?

You can certainly create something similar using Xamarin.Forms widgets. Just depends upon your requirements.